# When and where was the name "Kal-El" first used?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, history-of

When and where was the name **Kal-El** first used?

I know Jor-El (formerly Jor-L) was in the earlier prints. But, when was the name "Kal-El" first used/created to designate Superman?

Comment: At a minimum, I ran into it in the early 1970s, but I suspect it was earlier than that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's already in the [earliest newspaper comics from 1939](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306164334/http://www.thespeedingbullet.com/daily/ep01_15/ep1.html), though back then it's "Kal-L":

[image]

[According to this site](http://reading-room.net/SupermanDailiesOrigin/SupermanDailiesOriginCover.html):

> This is **the extended origin of Superman story which was told only in the daily newspaper comics in 1939** (about a year after Action Comics #1)! This tale has never appeared in a comic magazine!

"Kal-L" isn't mentioned in Action Comics #1, but I don't know if that name appears in any of the later issues.

---

WRT the name-change from "L" to "El", [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman#Superman_himself):

> The earliest newspaper strips name the planet "Krypton", the baby
> "Kal-L", and his biological parents "Jor-L" and "Lora"; their names
> become "Jor-el", and "Lara" in a 1942 spinoff novel by George Lowther.

The entry doesn't provide a link to back this up, instead it refers to a 2014 book which points to a 1942 book as the source of the name-change:

> Lowther, George (1942). *The Adventures of Superman*. Per Ricca
> (2014): "The book is also the first time that Superman's parents are
> named "Jor-el" and "Lara" — a slight spelling change that would stick."

The "per Ricca" refers to this:

> Ricca, Brad (2014). *Super Boys: The Amazing Adventures of Jerry Siegel
> and Joe Shuster – the Creators of Superman*. St. Martin's Griffin. ISBN
> 978-1250049681.

The [Wikipedia entry on the 1942 novel *The Adventures of Superman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Superman_(novel)) says that

> It was Lowther who first provided many now-familiar details of Superman's birth and early life. The first two chapters provided the first detailed description of the planet Krypton, and **renamed Kal-El's parents Jor-El and Lara who previously had been named Jor-L and Lora**.

Note that the book actually spells it "Jor-**el**" (as you can see in the scan below), it would later change to "Jor-**El**" in the comic books.

[image: excerpt from The Adventures of Superman by George Lowther]

Comment: I didn't know Superman was a newspaper comic first. That's pretty cool.

Comment: But when did it first become Kal-***E***l?

Comment: @Valorum their names become "Jor-el", and "Lara" in a 1942 spinoff novel by George Lowther.[108] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman#Fictional_character_biography

Comment: @BCdotWEB - At the moment I'm not entirely sure whether to downvote since your answer doesn't actually answer the question asked.

Comment: OP clearly isn't bothered with the L/El difference. He is asking for the first appearance of the name.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd It wasn't a newspaper comic first - the newspaper comics began about 6 months after Superman's first appearance in *Action Comics #1* in 1938.  This answer is saying that those newspaper comics use the name Kal-L.

Comment: @MartianInvader That's what it's saying *now*

Answer (score 10):

The first appearance of "Kal-el" is the 1940 [Superman Candy & Surprise](https://www.kandorarchives.com/p/1940-leader.html) trading card set, #33.

The same text appears on another 1940 release from [Superman Gum](https://www.kandorarchives.com/p/1940-gum.html) on card #1.
[image: 1940 Gum Inc. - Superman Gum #1]